# Error while trying to download youtube video using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
javascript:window.location.href = 'http://youtube.com/get_video?video_id=' + swfArgs['video_id']+ "&fmt=18" + "&l=" + swfArgs['l'] + "&sk=" + swfArgs['sk'] + '&fmt_map' + swfArgs['fmt_map'] + '&t=' + swfArgs['t'];
```

This gives me an error of swfArgs is not defined .

How to solve this ?

Comment: And where have you defined the `swfArgs` variable?

Comment: Well, your swfArgs dict is not defined (doesn't exist) - so the roots of the error are before that line. Can you provide any more code?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `var swfArgs={};` before that :) ...but this just makes te error go away. The ideea is that somehow in your code you don't get the "swfArgs" var.

Comment: Thats not going to help at all, its just going to be an empty dictionary.

Comment: The idea of answering a question, is to provide an solution to the problem, not a cheap hack that wont solve anything.

Comment: Oh, right, sry..so? how do you think he should solve this problem? oh, you can't because you don't have all the details right? Maybe if he saw he sould declare the var he would have something to go on from.. whatever..

Comment: ok relax people . I tried running the code in the console of google chrome toolkit . and thats the error I got . And var swfArgs={}; did work . So thank you . But the javascript piece of code didnt . So need to figure out another way to download youtube videos using the console

Comment: :) you don't need to figure out another way, you just have to provide the right parameters to the "swfArgs" obj like this: swfArgs['video_id']='id of the video'.... but it would really help if you provided more code to work with... (btw, that piece of code only redirects you to the page, running it in the console would be just like typing the address in the address bar)

Comment: waht if I dont want to go to any other page , and want to directly from the console . Is it possible?